# Where is registry stored in windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the Windows Registry Files stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/111311/where-is-the-windows-registry-files-stored)

I want to know where is registry stored in windows 7? I don't want to open it with regedit. I want the actual files and way to open them(because most of the time file formats are strange).

Comment: You really _really_ shouldn't be opening Registry hives with anything other than the registry editor, `regedit.exe`. Anything else is liable to break your entire system beyond any hope of repair.

Comment: I don't understand why this was migrated from StackOverflow, since it seems not only the locations but the formats are desired, and the format is definitely a programming question.

Comment: Second part of the question is related to programming. I also can't understand why they migrated it here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are called registry hive files. They are (mostly) located in the %SystemRoot%\System32\Config directory. [Much more info available in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724877(v=vs.85).aspx).

**Note: I would not touch these files with an infinitely long pole.**

Comment: I predict a question sometime soon along the lines of, "Help... I've corrupted my registry and now Windows won't start!" :p

Comment: HKCU is stored in `%Userprofile%\NTUser.dat`, though

Comment: I second this motion "Note: I would not touch these files with an infinitely long pole."

Comment: No problem touching them, as long as it's read-only.

Comment: There's a separate file for `HKCU\Software\Classes` too. (No idea where on W7, though.)

Comment: The cautionary statements are well taken, but there certainly are cases where it is desirable to access these hive files. For example, you might have the hard drive of a defunct computer, and you need to recover (read-only) some data from the old registry without actually booting Windows from the hard drive. Or you need to access it from a Linux box. What you do with that data afterwards is another matter...

Comment: @grawity, HKCU\Software\Classes registry hive is stored in %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat.  Windows 7 and 8 both, I believe.