# Reinstall XP on Existing Partition

Tags: windows, windows-xp, partitioning, reinstall

I would like to reinstall Windows XP on an existing partition. Loss of files does not matter because everything is safely backed up, but I do not want to lose installed programs. I have tried automatic repairs, but nothing seems to work. I essentially want my existing XP installation to be removed and replaced with loss of nothing else. How can I do this?

Comment: What has gone awry?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do this, so I'll describe this as best I can.

Assuming you have the original installation CD, boot from it. After it finishes loading the drivers, you will be taken to a selection. Press Enter.

Afterwards, the installation will ask you if you want to do a *fresh install* or a repair install. You want to repair. Select the partition that contains the Windows XP installation and follow the steps.

You might be asked to input your product key at one point of the process. The process is almost identical to the fresh installation process, barring that the CD actually *removes* most of the files present in `%windir%`.

[This](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/operatingsystems/ss/instxprepair1.htm) is probably more detailed than what I said here, so if you need additional guidance, use this guide.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One of the issues that I have here is the computer that I am trying to repair has Windows XP Home Edition, and I am trying to use my Windows XP Professional CD to repair. I managed to get the computer to boot after running automatic repair. The computer boots now, but whenever you try to open a program, it says "The procedure entry point EncodePointer could not be located in the
dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll." Any ideas? I tried to install Windows XP Service Pack 3 as per what Google told me to do, and it screwed things up again and it no longer boots once again.

Comment: Stands to reason that, being different versions, they shouldn't be compatible with each other (which is true, as Home has several features missing/disabled). Either get a Home CD or do a *clean install* (just remember to backup everything before). However that wouldn't help you a lot, as you want to keep your programs. Is there any reason you can't install them after?

Comment: The reason that I cannot reinstall the programs is because this is my friend's computer, and for whatever reason he is unable to reinstall the programs. Would it be possible for me to do a "clean install" by booting the computer using an Ubuntu CD and deleting all the files in "C:\WINDOWS"? The registry files need to be kept, but all other OS files can be wiped as long as they do not also result in the removal of software.

Comment: As [I learned recently](http://superuser.com/a/664499/228536), Windows stores the registry in a lot of files and places. Regardless, you ***shouldn't*** do that, as drivers and such stop being registered, and a lot of other problems might arise. Nothing grants you that programs store everything in the registry and that restoring it later will restore the settings. Please clarify the following: does your friend have the programs installation files' - If so, the best thing to do would be to have a clean slate. Afterwards the programs should install correctly.

Comment: For reference, I do have some "identical" problems, which is why I did this recently and coincidentally it's one of the reasons behind the linked answer (regarding some freak happening with Windows Installer) but for the moment they don't bug me.

Comment: My friend claims that he has the files somewhere, but he doesn't know where, and he has already looked everywhere that they may be. Could I try to do a new XP installation by upgrading to a cracked version of Windows 7 and then downgrading to XP again?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11306/discussion-between-doktoro-reichard-and-pwf)

Comment: Okay. Will StackExchange inform me whenever someone replies, or will I have to manually check it myself?

Comment: It will inform you when someone replies.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. I offered my friend an upgrade to Windows 7, and he accepted. After the upgrade, the computer worked fine, the software was still there, and although the files were missing, I restored backups.

Answer (score -1):

There's no (single) way to run **any** programs without any installation after reinstalling the OS

Only portable applications can run as-is on any system. Many apps have installers but in fact do not write anything in the system so they can run portably, i.e. no reinstallation

A few programs can run with some registry and/or files modification, possibly just a simple backup and then restore after reinstallation. But many others cannot run in anyway, even after restoring related registry keys and files and the only way to make them work is to reinstall from scratch

And you shouldn't stick with the ancient XP anymore