# Where are the Hardware Address / Device Files listed in Windows 10? (McAfee Solidifier CLI commands/Win10 in use)

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, pnp

Our company uses `McAfee Solidifier` to lock down our Terminal PC's.  I've been looking to find the *minimum required folder(s)* to `re-solidify` in order to allow **newly attached** peripherals to work and I'm wanting to narrow the focus of what we do currently to save time.

Right now I run `sadmin so C:\Windows\System32\` from a `Batch` file and this works to allow what we need, however, as mentioned, I want to be more granular in the `sadmin so` command.

> ***The question at hand: What is the most granular root directory I can use from Command Prompt / Batch files to solidify the necessary paths for Win 10 to allow my PNP Devices to behave, not including the `Drivers` or `DriverStore` folders below?  That is - Where does `Windows 10` store the files containing peripheral hardware data/addresses?***

Further reading as desired:

The issues we experience only happen when we are in the Windows 10 environment, and never in our Windows 7 environments.  From what I can only guess, there's a set of files which must be whitelisted in Win 10 by McAfee in order for McAfee to allow the peripherals to operate.  For full context, I do know of `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers` and `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore`, but I do not believe this is what I'm actually looking for.

**Examples:**

Windows 7 - adding a receipt Journal Printer which uses a COM Port (`PNP Device`), drivers are installed, and solidified (`sadmin so C:\Windows\System32`) without the Printer attached to the PC.  PC boots up, I can connect the printer of choice without any problems, it works right away, no errors seen in `Device Manager`

Windows 10 - same process as above, however, when I connect the Printer, it will not work without running `sadmin bu` on the Command Prompt to allow McAfee Solidifier to be in `Update mode`.  When I leave the Printer connected to the system and run `sadmin so C:\Windows\System32` it will allow the printer to work without having to be in `Update mode` on reboot, so I'm certain the files I'm looking for exist in `C:\Windows\System32` but are beyond the `Driver` or `DriverStore` directories.

Comment: Yes - McAfee Solidifier is Windows 10 compliant.  When I run the Solidify Command (`sadmin so`) on the `C:\Windows\System32` folder, it works, but ONLY if I have the Peripheral(s) connected, and I recall reading somewhere long ago that Windows 10 stores information for the Peripherals attached differently than Windows 7 - like a set if file(s) instead of what Windows 7 was doing.  (I tried posting this on StackOverflow since it has the McAfee flag, but it was closed immediately and said to post here. . .)

Comment: Also, the question isn't about whether or not the software works - it's specifically - "Where are these files found?" or "Where does Windows 10 store connected peripheral data/files?" - this is why it was closed on SO I believe.

Comment: so thats part of why I ask. unlike Linux, windows doesn't make files for its devices I/O. Can you better describe what you are looking for than "device files"? The way I'm imagining what you describe, it sounds like registry information.

Comment: I thought it was Registry information too, but I'm not sure and is part of the dilemma - where is it documented on how Windows stores this information, and is it documented anywhere that there is indeed a difference?  All I can determine at the moment is there has to be some kind of difference, or the Solidifier would not need to whitelist something while the device is connected for it to work (Windows 7 did not require this specifically)

Comment: The registry hives are stored in two places, one for system settings, and one for user settings: https://superuser.com/questions/111311/where-are-registry-files-stored-in-windows Also, some (too many, in my opinion) device drivers install various helper applications. I would suggest that you manage the drivers at the enterprise level, publishing them to the systems beforehand, and then, I believe, much of this conversation would be moot.

Comment: The issue isn't the drivers.  The issue is the difference in how Solidifier behaves in Windows 10 vs Windows 7 - I'm looking specifically for what the minimum required folders needing solidification are.  Why would drivers make a difference between one OS vs the other, when it's the exact same driver used in both cases?  Plus, they _are_ published before hand.  The issue is that the device **must** be plugged into the machine physically before the solidification takes place, otherwise the device is prevented from use.  This did not happen in Windows 7.

Comment: @music2myear, After carefully reading an article (https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2201309) and re-reading your comment, I retract my initial thought that it would not be driver related, and am fairly convinced the "virtual files" listed in this article are actually the Registry (the volatile sections listed in your article perhaps for some of it).  Either way, the drivers were a known requirement, but perhaps it's also the Registry with the stored hardware data being prevented from use in Win10 more "securely" than Win7 if it is not re-solidified with device plugged